# Vector notation to index (tensor) notation

Tags: vectors, tensors

I am trying to relate standard vector notation with the index notations used in tensor calculus. I have following query.

Assume A and B are two regular vectors in 3-D space, i.e. rank-1 tensors. ( $ A = A_x \mathbf{i} + A_y \mathbf{j} + A_z \mathbf{k} $, and so is B ).   So are the expressions $ A \cdot (\nabla B ) $ and $ (A \cdot\nabla) B $ equivalent? Going by the index notation, they do appear to be so, as  they seem to be resolving to the same expression. Please let me know if this analysis is correct, or I am doing something wrong.

$$
A \cdot (\nabla B ) = A^i (\nabla_i B^j) = A^i \nabla_i B^j
\\
(A \cdot\nabla) B = (A^i \nabla_i) B^j = A^i \nabla_i B^j 
$$

Comment: They give the same result, but they have different meanings. The second is the scalar operator $A\cdot\nabla$ applied to the vector $B$, whereas the first is a contraction of the vector $A$ with the matrix $\nabla B$.

Comment: Another useful exercise is to show that the objects $(A\cdot\nabla)B$ and $A\cdot\nabla B$ are both vectors, i.e, they transform as vectors under a coordinate transformation, to show that they are both equivalent in general.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not satisfied. If the two expressions give the same results, then they MUST have the same meanings.

Comment: So if the expression $2+2$ and the expression $2\cdot 2$ give the same result the operators $+$ and $\cdot$ MUST have the same meaning?

Comment: $A\cdot (\nabla B)$ is not well defined and depending on the context the interpretation can be $g_{jh}A^jB^h_{|k}$, $g^{jh}A_jB_{h|k}$ or even $A^jB^h_{|j}$ and so on.

Comment: @ContraKinta $\cdot$ is generally ambiguous when it comes to higher order tensors.

Comment: @ContraKinta you are using a mathematical trick. 2+2 and 2x2 give the same results because you are using specific numbers as arguments. In general a+b != a.b , so your argument is not valid.

Comment: @ContraKinta  <quote> $ A\cdot (\nabla B) $  is not well defined and depending on the context the interpretation can be  $ g_{jh}A^jB^h_{|k} $, $ g^{jh}A_jB_{h|k} $ , or even 
 $ A^jB^h_{|j} $ <end quote>. This is problematic statement. Aren't the first two terms really the same expression. $ g_{jh}A^jB^h_{|k}  = A_h B^h_{|k} = A^h B_{h|k} = g^{jh}A_jB_{h|k} $

Comment: I disagree with your definition of "same expression" and even with your definition based on "arguments" the first is a "dot" product of an (1,0)-tensor with a (1,1)-tensor. The second is a "dot" product of an (0,1)-tensor with an (0,2) tensor so in general you are not even using arguments from the same type of vector spaces.